# How to assign multiple class in my case?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to use multiple class for my element by using ng-class

I have something like

```
<div id='test'
ng-class="{blue: test}"
ng-class="scale ? 'scale' : 'non-scale'"
>
</div>
```

There are two conditions here and I am not sure how to combine these class into one ng-class statement. Can anyone help me about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="test" ng-class="{'blue':test, 'scale': scale, 'non-scale': !scale}">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="test" ng-class="{ 
       blue: test,
       scale: scale, 
       non-scale: !scale 
     }">
</div>
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, but if you didn't want to evaluate scale twice you can also use interpolation:

```
<div id="test" class="{{scale ? 'scale' : 'non-scale'}}" ng-class="{'blue':test}">
```

Or even refactoring your css to default to scale, and then you could add a 'non-scale' in the same way as blue does.